# Share div content as images in Facebook from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, share, screenshot, html

I'm working on a website, which is complete but for one thing I'm having a problem with. I have a page where I display team and player rankings in a dynamic div layout. I want to share these results in Facebook as images such as that shown below. How can I achieve this? Any idea where to start?

ASP code:

```
<div id="dvChartPosition" class="span12" runat="server">
<ul id="TAbLeaderBoard" class="nav nav-tabs nav-append-content">
    <li id="liGoalKeeper" runat="server" class="active" style="width: 55px; padding-right: 10px;">
        <a href="#BestGoalKeeper" data-toggle="tab"><span>Goalie</span></a></li>
    <li id="liStriker" runat="server" style="width: 55px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="#BestStriker"
        data-toggle="tab"><span>Striker</span></a></li>
    <li id="liDefender" runat="server" style="width: 65px; padding-right: 13px;"><a href="#BestDefender"
        data-toggle="tab"><span>Defender</span></a></li>
    <li id="liMidFielder" runat="server" style="width: 75px; padding-right: 13px;"><a
        href="#BestMidFielder" data-toggle="tab"><span>MidFielder</span></a></li>
    <li id="liManoftheMatch" runat="server" style="width: 50px; padding-right: 10px;"><a
        href="#ManoftheMatch" data-toggle="tab"><span>MoM</span></a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ManoftheMatch">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvManoftheMatch" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowHeader="true" CssClass="table table-striped" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Rank" DataField="Rank" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="PlayerName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i have taken the screenshot of body content but couldnot screenshot of div in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched but nothing found. But now i found a way to share a div. You can only share images not div in facebook.
 So i took screenshot of my div with [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) 
then i [social plugin](http://www.addinto.com/)
Maybe this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

You can probably convert the div into a PDF or image and then share it on Facebook?

Comment: I have already converted div to image but now im struggling to find or make a javascript function which will first convert the div in image and then share it on facebook. now first part is complete second is pending.